# what does it mean by println(f(a))?

Tags: scala

```
object MainObject {  
   def main(args: Array[String]) = {  
     functionExample(25, multiplyBy2)                   // Passing a function as parameter  
    }  
    def functionExample(a:Int, f:Int=>AnyVal):Unit = {  
        println(f(a))                                   // Calling that function   
    }  
    def multiplyBy2(a:Int):Int = {  
        a*2  
    }  
}
```

Comment: it prints the result of calling the function f with the argument a. f is a function pointer that was passed as an argument, in your case it points to `multiplyBy2`

Answer (score 1):

If you add this line to build.sbt:

`scalacOptions += "-Xprint:jvm"`

Then while compiling it will produce the following desugared version of this code:

```
[[syntax trees at end of                       jvm]] // Test.scala
package <empty> {
  object MainObject extends Object {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = MainObject.this.functionExample(25, {
      {
        $anonfun()
      }
    });
    def functionExample(a: Int, f: Function1): Unit = scala.Predef.println(f.apply(scala.Int.box(a)));
    def multiplyBy2(a: Int): Int = a.*(2);
    final <static> <artifact> def $anonfun$main$1(a: Int): Int = MainObject.multiplyBy2(a);
    def <init>(): MainObject.type = {
      MainObject.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see `f(a)` is actually `f.apply(scala.Int.box(a))` in reality. So the `apply` method of the function `f` which is an instance of the `Function1`  type gets executed. After which you print its result.

It was already mentioned in the earlier comment to your question but I think desugared version of the code helps to understand better.